# Help me sort NSMutableArray full of NSDictionary objects - Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableArray full of NSDictionary objects. Like so

```
NSMutableArray *names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *string in pathsArray) {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/etc/%@",string];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:string,@"name",path,@"path",nil];
}
```

pathsArray is not sortable, so I'm stuck with the order of objects inside of it.  I would like to sort the names array in alphabetical order of the objects for the key: @"name" in the dictionary.  Can this be done easily or will it take several levels of enumeration?

EDIT:  I Found the answer on SO in this question: [Sort NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556801/sort-nsmutablearray)

NSSortDescriptor class.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[names sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortName]];
[sortName release];
```

Anyone care to get some free answer points?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                          ascending:YES] autorelease];
 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
 NSArray *sortedArray = [names sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

 // names : the same name of the array you provided in your question.
```

Comment: Any reason why you've weirdly created variables without assigning values to them immediately?

Comment: How can we make this case insensitive? Because as of now, the capital letters comes first.. example: ABCabc

Comment: @VanDuTran use `selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]`

Comment: @AhmadKayyali, that wouldn't work as I have an NSArray of NSDictionary and not of Strings :)